# unable to connect to https site on via both code and native browser

Tags: android

I have an android application that makes a https connection to a backend. I have successfully added the required certificate (obtained from the backend and converted to bks format) and the app can connect when running on 2.2, 2.3 and 4.0.2 emulators. However on my huawei u8860 (honor) with ics 4.0.3, the app doesn't connect and worst of all it doesn't give any exceptions in the log. On the phone also, I can't point the native browser to the backend but i can using google-chrome for android. I've searched high and low on but found no explanation for this behaviour. any ideas?! Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you you use the same mobile data carrier / wifi network for all your tests ?

Comment: for the emulators i can only use the pc's connection. But for the phone i'm using my data carrier's 3g connection and i can browse the backend using google-chrome android browser but i can't using the android native browser or via code.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is caused by your mobile carrier.
Some of them perform nasty filtering of HTTP requests, based on the `User-Agent` header (they'll block requests that do not seem to come from a mobile device).

You should try your app on your phone, using a **Wifi connection** to confirm/infirm this hypothesis.

If it works on Wifi, you should try to change the User-Agent of your HTTP requests, by either setting it to:

- A hard-coded Android Chrome or iPhone Safari User-Agent (that you carrier probably does not block)
- The User-Agent of your own device's browser that you should get with [getUserAgentString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#getUserAgentString%28%29)

Comment: I tried connecting via WiFi and the app connected. So I tried hard coding the user-agent setting from the chrome for android browser (since that connects) but no success. I also tried other user-agents with no success as well. I just check the response code and it's error code 400 (bad request). So i'm guessing that the mobile carrier is "limiting" the request size for https connections and not http.